# Serializing data with AWS Ion

Tags: amazon-web-services, serialization

I need to serialize data in binary format and transport it over BLE. First I looked into Protobuf.  But it doesn't support framing, self describing message and random access - a few capabilities I need for my project.  AWS ion supports self describing message and random access to message.  But I haven't found a complete example how to serialize a transport an IonStruct over BLE.  Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What's BLE, and which language are you using?

Comment: BLE = Bluetooth low energy.  I am using Java.